# Http.Page.Request[" "] not returning correct values

Tags: asp.net, request

**Situation:-**
There is a Home.aspx page, which can be opened by a unique user ("userName" variable).

This page has a popup window control name 'alertWindow'.

In the pageLoad event of Home.aspx.cs, Welcome.aspx page is opened in the 'alertWindow' using NavigateUrl property.

The querystring passed to Welcome.aspx page contains a parameter "UserName" and this parameter is set to the logged in user's name ("userName" variable).

Now when the code execution comes to Welcome.aspx.cs page, "Request["UserName"]" is used to get\retrieve the current "userName" paramerter existing in the query string.

**Issue:-**
When a logged-in user's name has space or other non-usual characters, then "Request["UserName"].ToString()" doesn't retrieve the actual and correct value.

For Ex. if the logged in "userName" = "A&T Telecom", then "Request["UserName"].ToString() retrieves only "A" and nothing else.

But if the userName string is a proper value like "micheal", then "Request["UserName"].ToString() retrieves only "Micheal" correctly

**Requirement:-**
Please provide a way so that I get the correct value from Request["UserName"] for any kind of "userName" string value.

**Home.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (user is valid)
       alertWindow.NavigateUrl = "Welcome.aspx?userName=" + currentUser.ToString();
}
```

**Welcome.aspx.cs**:-

```
currentUserName = Request["userName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is logical because you do not [Encode your url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx). Try this:

```
alertWindow.NavigateUrl = "Welcome.aspx?userName=" + Server.UrlEncode(currentUser.ToString());
```

To say few more, they are some special characters that used on the URL, like the

`: / # ? & @ % + (and the space)`.

All that characters must be encode to a different format, so the url will not break, the UrlEncode do exactly that.

Two notes.

1. I select the `Server` to call the UrlEncode because is not depend from the Request, and you can use it inside a thread, or any function that is not called from the Page.
2. The `Request.QueryString` make UrlDecode when you use it. To get the encode url you call the `Request.RawUrl`

Comment: Great explanation in short , mentioned in Two Notes. Thanks a ton Aristos. Soution worked.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add white spaces within your url, it needs encoding so :

```
//uses HttpUtility.UrlEncode internally

Server.UrlEncode("something with spaces");
```

or

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("something with spaces");
```